# ¿Cómo obtener todas las combinaciones posibles entre elementos que no pertenecen a un mismo grupo? (con JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

Tengo un array de grupos (uno o muchos), y cada grupo tiene uno o muchos valores. Y quisiera una función que me retorne todas las posibles combinaciones entre los valores. Y un valor no se combinará con otro valor del mismo grupo.
Ejemplo: [ [pantalon1, pantalon2], [camisa1, camisa2] ]. Y la respuesta sería:
[ [pantalon1, camisa1], [pantalon1, camisa2], [pantalon2, camisa1], [pantalon2, camisa2] ]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrarnos lo que has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: El código debe ir en formato texto y no en imagen. Por favor haz clic en [edit] y corrige tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

creo que esto devuelve lo que necesitas, lo encerré en una función aunque era innecesario, pero así puedo hacer un return, y podrías hacer en ese lugar lo que desees, o al momento de los push.

```
const grupos = [
  ["Pantalon1", "Pantalon2", "Pantalon3", "Pantalon4"],
  ["Camisa1", "Camisa2", "Camisa3"],
  ["Zapatos1", "Zapatos2"],
];

let auxCombinacionesFinal = []
let auxCombinacionesTemporal = []

/* Lista items primer grupo, deposito en auxiliar que
 utilizaré para formar las combinaciones */
for (const item of grupos[0]) {
  auxCombinacionesFinal.push(item)
}

const generarCombinaciones = ()=>{
/* Recorro todos los elementos desde la posición 1 de grupos hasta
el final, y en cada grupo concateno con los de la primer lista */
for (let indice = 1; indice < grupos.length; indice++) {
  auxCombinacionesTemporal=[]
  for (const item of auxCombinacionesFinal) {
    for (const elem of grupos[indice]) {
      auxCombinacionesTemporal.push(item + " " + elem)
    }
  }
  //Igualo la lista y la vació arriba para seguir usando la temporal
  auxCombinacionesFinal = auxCombinacionesTemporal
}
return auxCombinacionesFinal
}

generarCombinaciones()
```

Espero sirva.

Comment: EXCELENTE! Muchas Gracias!

Comment: Estuvo complicado, pero me alegra haber podido ayudar, quedo a las órdenes. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Armé esto, quizás no sean las funciones más performantes, pero espero te ayuden a encontrar el camino adecuado, sabemos que for dentro de for no es lo más óptimo, pero funciona..

Opción 1 (Busca todas las posibilidades, pero ejemplo repite pantalon - camisa y luego camisa - pantalon):

```
let contador = 0;

const grupos = [
  ["BB", "SS", "PP", "XX"],
  ["a", "b", "c"],
  ["OO", "EE"],
];

const arrayCompleto = [];

for (const grupo of grupos) {
  for (const valor of grupo) {
    arrayCompleto.push(valor);
  }
}

for (const value1 of arrayCompleto) {
  for (const value2 of arrayCompleto) {
    if (value2 !== value1) {
        contador++
      console.log(contador, value1, value2);
    }
  }
}
```

Opción 2 (Busca todas las posibilidades, pero ejemplo elimina las repeticiones ej: si hay pantalon - camisa no agrega camisa - pantalon):

```
let contador = 0;

const grupos = [
  ["BB", "SS", "PP", "XX"],
  ["a", "b", "c"],
  ["OO", "EE"],
];

const arrayCompleto = [];
const arrayFinal = [];
for (const grupo of grupos) {
  for (const valor of grupo) {
    arrayCompleto.push(valor);
  }
}

for (const value1 of arrayCompleto) {
  for (const value2 of arrayCompleto) {
    if (value2 !== value1) {
      contador++;
      console.log(contador);
      arrayFinal.push({value1, value2});
    }
}
arrayCompleto.shift();
}

console.log(arrayFinal);
```

En ambas opciones agregué un contador para ver la cantidad de registros y verificar si los resultados son correctos, también en el último ejemplo agregué un clg al final para ver como queda el resultado final.

Básicamente lo que hago es grupos de grupos es decir arrays de arrays, de esa forma puedes agregar tantos grupos como desees de tantos elementos como desees. Entonces primero recorro cada grupo y cada valor, y pongo todos los valores de todos los grupos en un único array. Luego recorro este array y por cada elemento recorro el array devuelta y agrego cada combinación siempre que el valor no sea igual para que no quede ejemplo (camisa-camisa).
Ese procedimiento lo repito por cada elemento del arrayCompleto hasta hacer todas las combinaciones, tras terminar de agregar todos las combinaciones con ejemplo "camisa", elimino camisa del array completo, de esa manera no aparecerá ningún repetido invertido.

Espero te sirva, quedo a las órdenes.

---

Agrego esta opción, no permite repetidos cruzados y tampoco agrega del mismo grupo.

Las combinaciones las agrega como string dentro de un array ej: "pantalon1 - camisa2", al final los muestra todos y devuelve también su length para corroborar que sea correcto. En este código también puedes agregar cuantas listas desees al array grupos de cuantos elementos desees.

```
let combinaciones = [];

const grupos = [
  ["Pantalón1", "Pantalón2", "Pantalón3", "Pantalón4"],
  ["Camisa1", "Camisa2", "Camisa3"],
  ["Zapato1", "Zapatos2"],
];

for (let i = 0; i < grupos.length; i++) {
  for (const item of grupos[i]) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < grupos.length; j++) {
      grupos[j].map((elem) => {
        combinaciones.push(`${item} - ${elem}`);
      });
    }
  }
}
console.log(combinaciones)
console.log("Total de posibles combinaciones: " + combinaciones.length);
```

Espero con este puedas resolver, quedo a las órdenes.

Comment: Creo que no me expliqué bien. Los valores no pueden combinarse con ningún otro de su mismo grupo, es decir, "BB" no puede combinarse con "SS" ni "PP" ni "XX". Y "a" no se puede combinar con "b" ni con "c". La combinación es entre grupos. En tu ejemplo solo existen 24 posibles combinaciones correctas.
1) ["BB", "a", "OO"]
2) ["BB", "a", "EE"]
3) ["BB", "b", "OO"]
4) ["BB", "b", "EE"]
5) ["BB", "c", "OO"]
6) ["BB", "c", "EE"]
........... etc

Comment: Edité la solución, agregué otra solución al final que es más corta y contempla todas las opciones, sin repetir de la misma categoría, también les puse nombres de prendas para que sea más sencillo corroborar, me están dando 26 posibilidades, capaz me equivoqué. Quedo atento.

Comment: Cada combinación debe tener un elemento de cada grupo, ejemplo:
1) pantalon1 - camisa1 - zapato1
2) pantalon1 - camisa1 - zapato2
etc